# Active slider only in small resolution

Tags: jquery, css

i'm building a responsive website, whith a couple of 'prices & plans' of the service. But, in small resolutions, there is a lot of information to show. So i want to use a slider and show each 'prices & plans' in a single slider. The problem is, because of the way slider works (insert other divs on the window load) the slider is not activating. Does anyone knows another way to do this?

This is what i was trying to do with Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).load(function() {
        getWidthAndHeight();
    });
    $(window).resize(function() {
        getWidthAndHeight();
    });

   if ($(window).width() < 768) {   
        $('.e-price-sh').addClass('slider');
    } else {
        $('.e-price-sh').removeClass('slider');
    };

)};
```

Ps.: I was able to get the result i want, but i have to blocks of code in my html, one of them is with a class hidden for res. bigger than 768 and the other with class hidden for res. smaller than 768

This is the html, i want to append the slider with the  e-price-sh class:

```
    <h3>Prices & Plans</h3>

    <div class="e-price-sh">
        <div class="e-price-col">
        ...
        </div>

        <div class="e-price-col">
        ...
        </div>

        <div class="e-price-col">
        ...
        </div>

        <div class="e-price-col">
        ...
        </div>

        <div class="e-price-col">
        ...
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **media query** to Achieve:

```
.e-price-sh{display:none;}


 @media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    .e-price-sh{display:block;}
}
```

What's more:
if you use [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/). There is a class named: `.show-fow-small-only` to resolve it quickly.

Comment: The reason why i don't want to do that is because each 'price & plan' will be on vertically aligned, the page is going to be taller and it's going to be hard to read the information. With the slider i can display only one 'price&plan' at a time and the user can switch and see other. I hope i can make my explanation clear =D